# When is open data not open?

Tags: uk, open-definition

I saw that Glasgow (I live there) is boasting about their open data (http://open.glasgow.gov.uk/). Yet I saw [a tweet](https://twitter.com/chillly/status/432539985841889282) from an OpenStreet Map/Open data enthusiast:

"It seems that, in spite of the hype, @openglasgow open data is not open. So Open Glasgow == closed data just called open. #datatrap"

As someone who is just trying to get their head around open data can anyone explain this comment?

Comment: best would be to get an explanation of the original poster.

Comment: @Ulrich Thank you, however I am not on twitter or facebook. I appreciate the feedback, and your answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### All open data are good, but some are better.

In a colloquial way: *open* means that everyone can use it, for any purpose. The idea is that you have as few technical, financial and legal barriers as possible.

Quite a popular definition is the one from the [OKF](http://opendefinition.org):

> “A piece of data or content is open if anyone is free to use, reuse, and redistribute it — subject only, at most, to the requirement to attribute and/or share-alike.”

I believe this becomes more clear when we enter the "grey areas":

- Open usually means free. However, sometimes it may include a nominal fee when the publication of data is costly.
- Open usually **avoids** a non-commercial licence. Excluding commercial activities brings the uncertainty of the exact definition of "non-commercial" and its potential legal ramifications.
- Twitter is also somewhere in between. Some people argue it's "open" (e.g J. Gurin in *Open Data Now*) perhaps because of its public nature. However, there are serious restrictions of who and how you can use Twitter data.

#### Glasgow

On their [site](http://data.glasgow.gov.uk/about) they write

> Glasgow City Council data is now open by default, freely and easily
>   accessible to all.

Unfortunately, the link to "open by default" goes nowhere at the moment. The licence would explain what you can and cannot do with it. I would assume (and I may be wrong) that the [Open Government Licence](http://www.nationalarchives.gov.uk/doc/open-government-licence/version/2/) applies. It is relatively generous and easy to read.

Comment: I would tend to agree that it is likely licensed under the UK Open Government License :  "Open Glasgow itself is part of a larger project: “Future Cities”. Glasgow received a grant from the UK Government's Technology Strategy Board to demonstrate how combining expertise with cutting-edge technology can enhance day-to-day life in the city. "